# How to make CSS sourcemapping work in Chrome with Compass (SASS)

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools, compass

the thing is that I'm trying to get CSS mapping working with my Compass project in Chrome (v38, OS X) so It reloads my CSS without the need to reload page.

I followed this https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors and also this http://www.sitepoint.com/using-source-maps-debug-sass-chrome/

I have fully working Compass project and I'm compiling using `compass watch`.

Into `Config.rb` I have added `sourcemap = true` and `.map` file has been successfully created.

When I load my site, I can see `.map` file loaded in Network tab in Console (status code 200)

`Enable CSS source maps` and `Auto-reload generated CSS` is also on in Chrome's Settings.

But when I recompile css changes don't appear in DevTools nor in page. However when I reopen DevTools I can see changes in Styles tab but they're not applied into page.

### So, to sum up:

- I have no problems with Compass compilation etc.
- `.map` file is compiled and loaded through my HTTP server with 200 OK response
- I can see `.scss` references in Style inspector eg. `body {...} style.scss:18` so Chrome communicated with my `.map` file
- When my SCSS is compiled, changes appear in DevTools only when I reopen it
- After reopening, I can see CSS changes in Style tab but they're not applied into my page

Any ideas what might be the issue here? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've missed a few steps :

***Chrome < 53***

1. Enable CSS source maps in Chrome (<kbd>DevTools</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd>)
2. Enable auto-reload generated CSS source map in Chrome (<kbd>DevTools</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd>)
3. Add your project folder in the Chrome workspace (<kbd>DevTools</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Workspace</kbd>)
4. Chrome ask you for a full access to this folder, accept
5. In the <kbd>Sources</kbd> tab, find your generated CSS file, right click on it and choose <kbd>Map to network ressource</kbd>, and select the same file name in the shown dropdown
6. Chrome ask you to reload DevTools, accept

***Chrome >= 53***

1. Enable CSS source maps in Chrome (<kbd>DevTools</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Sources</kbd>)
2. In the <kbd>Sources</kbd> tab, right click anywhere and choose <kbd>Add folder to workspace</kbd>, and select your project folder.
3. Chrome ask you for a full access to this folder, accept
4. In the <kbd>Sources</kbd> tab, find your generated CSS file, right click on it and chosse <kbd>Map to file system ressource</kbd>, and select the same file name in the shown dropdown

Now, you can change your Sass file in your favorite editor (you then need to watch it, or relaunch `sass` command), **or directly in Chrome Devtools**: select your file, edit it and save it.

Comment: 1. and 2. I did as written above and even though I don't want to save my CSS from DevTools (for that functionality the Workspace must be set so far as I understand it so that shouldn't be necessary for me either) you pointed me to read a paragraph I missed saying `Changes made in an external editor are not detected by DevTools until the Sources tab containing the associated source file regains focus. Also, manual editing of a CSS file generated by the Sass/LESS/other compiler will break the source map association until the page is reloaded.` So yea, that's pretty much it :) Thanks

Comment: @zessx  Hi, I dont see any option in dropdown for mapping the css file..

Comment: @angular2 I updated my answer to take Chrome 53+ in account.

Comment: @zessx: I still dont get any option in dropdown to select a file.Yes I am using chrome 53.

Comment: @zessx : Please see my detailed query here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487990/gulp-sourcemaps-scss-not-available-in-chrome