# Chrome Dev Tools - Mapping network resource - How to map to a directory

Tags: sass, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to use the feature "Mapping network resource" to see my .scss files. So I mapped my main.css file to my main.scss.

The issue I have is that my main.scss contains only @import instructions :

```
// Utils
@import 'utils/colors';
@import 'utils/bootstrap-variables';
@import 'utils/functions';
@import 'utils/variables';
@import 'utils/mixins';

// Vendors
@import 'vendors/bootstap';
@import 'font-awesome';

// Base
@import 'base/reset';
@import 'base/typography';

// Components
@import 'components/state';
@import 'components/panel-dashboard';
@import 'components/modal';
```

So when I inspect my DOW elements, I don't see the real .scss ressources, but only the main.scss ressource.

Comment: Are you using sourcemaps?

Comment: Yes the sourcemap is well generated with https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass

Comment: Following these instructions should be enough http://stackoverflow.com/a/26459731/1593273

Comment: I did, but still have the problem. I only see my main.scss file from the inspect element panel, and not the all the .scss files imported by the main.scss where my classes a defined.

Comment: You should be mapping the root folder that your SASS lives in, rather than the individual file.

Comment: I don't think we can do such a thing :( Do you know how ? I tried, but it doesn't work ...