# Debug source maps loading on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, minify, source-maps, gulp-sourcemaps

I generate source maps for javascript files during minification. The map files are referenced using a relative URL from the minified JS files that sit next to the map files. Here is an example comment at the end of `app-e47a6637.js`:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=app-e47a6637.js.map
```

The source map resolution works as expected in Firefox. However, Chrome does not load the map files.

Additional information:

- JS source maps are of course enabled in the settings.
- I tried putting a proxy between Chrome and the server. Chrome does not even request the map files.
- I use `gulp-sourcemaps` to generate the map files.
- I don't want to use the workspace feature of Chrome. I just want it to display the original source files.

**How can I enable source maps in Chrome?**

Comment: Are your sourcemaps being served? ( can you view them if you point your browser directly at them? ) Another thing you might try is an 'empty cache and hard reload' I've noticed chrome seems to cache source stuff pretty deep.

Comment: @BenJamin Yes they are, otherwise it wouldn't work in Firefox. I can download the map files in both FF and Chrome. Clearing the cache also did not improve the situation.

Comment: is the Source Map URL correct?

Comment: @BenJamin I don't know if you saw my comment: "... otherwise it wouldn't work in Firefox. I can download the map files in both FF and Chrome." So yes, the URL is correct.

Comment: In the web inspector, under settings, is "Enable JavaScript source maps" checked?

Comment: @casraf Yes, it says so in the question text.

Comment: I mean does the sourceMappingURL in the source file have the correct path relative to the source file.

Comment: This worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/33488335/560287